# What's Wrong With My SQL Code?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, oledb

I get this error

> The specified field 'StockID' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

Code:

```
 cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT StockID as [Stock ID], ea.Products as [Product]," & _
                         "emp.Amount FROM Stock ea inner join tblProductDetails" & _
                         "emp on emp.StockID = ea.StockID", con)
```

I've set the relationship to `tblProductDetails`'s `stockID` to `Stock`

Sorry for any obvious mistake.

Comment: Try `"SELECT ea.StockID as [Stock ID] ...`

Comment: there's an ambiguity in your SELECT part of the query, "StockID" is present in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both your tables (Stock and tblProductDetails) has a field called [Stock ID].  you will need to specify which one to use (either emp or ea)

Comment: without knowing what data you are after i can only suggest.  use either **"SELECT emp.StockID as [Stock ID], ea.Products as [Product]," & _
                         "emp.Amount FROM Stock ea inner join tblProductDetails" & _
                         "emp on emp.StockID = ea.StockID"**

or 

**"SELECT ea.StockID as [Stock ID], ea.Products as [Product]," & _
                         "emp.Amount FROM Stock ea inner join tblProductDetails" & _
                         "emp on emp.StockID = ea.StockID"**

Comment: Fixed my code just needed a space. Thanks a lot! Understood better!

Answer (score 5):

It means that the specified field 'StockID' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

In other words, both `Stock` and `tblProductDetails` have a field named `StockID`, and it isn't sure which one you mean.

You have to qualify it with the table name, e.g. `SELECT ea.StockID` or `SELECT emp.StockID`.

Even though you're joining and they both have the same value, you still have to specify one. In your case, with an inner join, the choice is fairly arbitrary.